# Spring MVC + PrimeFaces + Class config/Annotations

Tags: spring-mvc, primefaces

I'm trying to add PrimeFaces 5 to my current project with SpringMVC.
My problem is that I don't know how to translate this XML config to class based config:

```
<application>
     <el-resolver>
      org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
     </el-resolver>
</application>
```

I don't use XML's for configuration. Maybe it must to be included in WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.